# Update a column in a SQL table using the value of the same Column from the previous row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with the following layout and values,

[image: Table Initial Layout]
I want the data for 'PrevMonthly Amount' column to be updated based on the following rule,

For the combination of REFNO & KEY,

- If a transaction is the 1st transaction then PrevMonthly Amount = 0
- If a transaction is the 1st transaction in a new month (I.e.) there
  is a change in DATE then PrevMonthly Amount = Prev Amount
- Otherwise PrevMonthly Amount = PrevMonthly Amount from the previous
  transaction for the same combination of REFNO & KEY

Final expected result would be,

[image: Table Result]

I tried using the LAG function in SQL but I was not getting the expected the result as shown above.

```
SELECT REFNO, KEY, SEQNO,  
LAG(DATE,1) OVER (PARTITION BY REFNO, KEY ORDER BY REFNO, KEY, SEQNO) as DATE_Prev  
INTO #TEMP_TABLE  
FROM MainTable  

UPDATE A SET  
A.PrevMonthlyAmount = CASE WHEN A.DATE <> B.DATE_Prev  
THEN A.PrevAmount ELSE A.PrevMonthlyAmount END              

FROM MainTable A  
JOIN #Temp_Table B  
ON A.REFNO = B.REFNO And A.KEY = B.KEY And A.SEQNO = B.SEQNO

UPDATE A SET  
A.PrevMonthlyAmount = CASE WHEN A.DATE = B.DATE_PREV  
THEN (SELECT PrevMonthlyAmount From STAGE_LARGE_BANDED Where SEQNO = A.SEQNO - 1 And REFNO = A.REFNO And KEY = A.KEY AND)  
ELSE A.PrevMonthlyAmount END                         

FROM MainTable A  
JOIN #Temp_Table B  
ON A.REFNO = B.REFNO And A.KEY = B.KEY And A.SEQNO =  B.SEQNO
```

Data set I have indicated in the table layout is just a sample and am working on table which would have close to few million rows in a real time scenario.

Result which I got for my query is as follows,

[image]

Create Table & INSERT Queries are as follows,

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MAINTABLE](
        [REFNO] [int] NULL,
        [KEY]   [Int] NULL, 
        [SEQNO] [int] NULL, 
        [DATE]  [int] NULL, 
        [AMOUNT] [int] NULL,
        [PrevAMOUNT] [int] NULL,
        [PrevMonthlyAmount] [int] NULL,
     ) 

     INSERT INTO MAINTABLE Values(1000000,2,1,201801,100,0,0)
     INSERT INTO MAINTABLE Values(1000000,2,2,201801,200,100,0)
     INSERT INTO MAINTABLE Values(1000000,2,3,201802,300,200,0)
     INSERT INTO MAINTABLE Values(1000000,2,4,201802,400,300,0)
     INSERT INTO MAINTABLE Values(1000000,2,5,201802,420,400,0)
     INSERT INTO MAINTABLE Values(1000000,2,6,201803,450,400,0)

     INSERT INTO MAINTABLE Values(2000000,1,1,201801,150,0,0)
     INSERT INTO MAINTABLE Values(2000000,1,2,201801,250,150,0)
     INSERT INTO MAINTABLE Values(2000000,1,3,201801,350,250,0)

     INSERT INTO MAINTABLE Values(3000000,1,1,201801,175,0,0)
     INSERT INTO MAINTABLE Values(3000000,1,2,201802,275,175,0)
     INSERT INTO MAINTABLE Values(3000000,1,3,201803,375,275,0)
```

Comment: What result were you getting instead of the expected result?

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for your comments... I tried using LAG for the PrevMonthly Amoutn column but not getting the desired result as this itself is being a calculated column !!!

Comment: `LAG` does what you tell it to do. What *does* the first `SELECT` return? Add a `CREATE TABLE` and an `INSERT VALUES` script so we can try this without having to type all that data from the screenshots

Comment: Please don't post images of data; it isn't useful to the volunteers you're asking help from. Your data is text, please do post it as `text`. Thank you

Comment: Your rule n°3 is basically the same as the 2nd one, by refno and key.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the query for creating and inserting data into the table. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can `apply` :

```
select t.*, t1.prevmonthly_amount
from table t outer apply
    (select top (1) t1.amount as prevmonthly_amount
     from table t1
     where t.refno = t1.refno and t.key = t1.key and
           t1.date < t.date
     order by  t1.seqno desc
    ) t1;
```

Comment: The OP is already using `LAG`. The date isn't part of the partition key or `ORDER BY` clause

Comment: This doesn't work for the second set of refno/key.  Also, there is no reason to split the date into parts.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos. . . Correct.

Comment: @GordonLinoff. .  Yes it is redundant

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . the previous monthly amount appears to be the first value for the month.  So, I think this works for your data:

```
select t.*,
       first_value(prevamount) over (partition by refno, key, date order by seqno) as prevmonthly_amount
from t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=515e42aa106eccd74e172834de2dd482) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks very much for all your time and inputs.

I tried few things around solving my question and found a resolution !!!

But I definitely believe there could be some better solution than this anyways...:):)

Please see below,

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MAINTABLE](
    [REFNO] [int] NULL,
    [KEY] [int] NULL,
    [SEQNO] [int] NULL,
    [DATE] [int] NULL,
    [AMOUNT] [int] NULL,
    [PrevAMOUNT] [int] NULL,
    [PrevMonthlyAmount] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]


 Truncate Table MAINTABLE

 INSERT INTO MAINTABLE Values(1000000,2,1,201801,100,0,0)
 INSERT INTO MAINTABLE Values(1000000,2,2,201801,200,100,0)
 INSERT INTO MAINTABLE Values(1000000,2,3,201802,300,200,0)
 INSERT INTO MAINTABLE Values(1000000,2,4,201802,400,300,0)
 INSERT INTO MAINTABLE Values(1000000,2,5,201802,420,400,0)
 INSERT INTO MAINTABLE Values(1000000,2,6,201803,450,420,0)

 INSERT INTO MAINTABLE Values(2000000,1,1,201801,150,0,0)
 INSERT INTO MAINTABLE Values(2000000,1,2,201801,250,150,0)
 INSERT INTO MAINTABLE Values(2000000,1,3,201801,350,250,0)

 INSERT INTO MAINTABLE Values(3000000,1,1,201801,175,0,0)
 INSERT INTO MAINTABLE Values(3000000,1,2,201802,275,175,0)
 INSERT INTO MAINTABLE Values(3000000,1,3,201803,375,275,0)

SELECT REFNO, [KEY], SEQNO,  
LAG(DATE,1) OVER (PARTITION BY REFNO, [KEY] ORDER BY REFNO, [KEY], SEQNO) as DATE_Prev  
INTO #TEMP_TABLE  
FROM MainTable  

UPDATE A SET  
A.PrevMonthlyAmount = 
CASE WHEN A.DATE <> B.DATE_Prev  
    THEN A.PrevAmount 
    ELSE A.PrevMonthlyAmount
 END              

FROM MainTable A  
JOIN #Temp_Table B  
ON A.REFNO = B.REFNO And A.[KEY] = B.[KEY] And A.SEQNO = B.SEQNO

SELECT A.* 
INTO #TEMP_TABLE2
FROM MAINTABLE A 
JOIN (SELECT REFNO, [KEY], [DATE], MIN(SEQNO) as FirstTransId From MAINTABLE
        GROUP BY REFNO, [KEY], [DATE]) B
ON A.REFNO = B.REFNO And A.[KEY] = B.[KEY] And A.[DATE] = B.[DATE] And A.SEQNO = B.FirstTransId


UPDATE A SET  
A.PrevMonthlyAmount = B.PrevMonthlyAmount

FROM MainTable A  
JOIN #TEMP_TABLE2 B  
ON A.REFNO = B.REFNO And A.[KEY] = B.[KEY] And A.[DATE] =  B.[DATE]  
Where A.SEQNO <> B.SEQNO

Select * from MAINTABLE
```